# Should I say "Thank you for your kindly attention" or "Thank you for you kind attention"

Tags: vocabulary

Which is more correct?

> "Thank you for your Kindly attention."
>   "Thank you for you Kind Attention."

Comment: Welcome! In order for us to help you better, please explain what about these two sentences is confusing you and which you think is correct. Check out [this information](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2416/16318) to see how to improve your question.

Answer (score 8):

I think the most natural phrasing would be:

> Thank you for your kind attention.

Note that it is *your* instead of *you*, and that *kind attention* should not be capitalized as it is not a proper noun

*Kindly* can be used in a few different ways, none of which apply to your first sentence:

- As an adverb, meaning *in a kind way*.  This usage does not make sense in your first sentence: since you are using *kindly* to modify *attention*, you need an adjective.
- As an adjective, meaning *kind* or *gentle*.  But in this sense it is usually only used to apply to people.  You could speak of *a kindly gentleman* but not *a kindly gift*.
- In the set phrase *thank you kindly*, meaning *thank you very much*.  You could rephrase as *Thank you kindly for your attention* if you want, but the meaning is slightly different.  This may also come across as old-fashioned.

Comment: Webster says kindly concern, kindly climate. Kindly criticism  - The Free Dictionary. Kindly act - Cambridge.  There so many examples in other dictionaries; they have used kindly as an adjective not only for people but also for an act.

Comment: @Khan Could you add a couple of links to the examples using *kindly* as an adjective? I wonder if there is a specific usage.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kindly

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/kindly

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kindly

Answer (score 4):

OP's first version probably reflects the dated/archaic form *[**I**] **thank you kindly** for your attention* - but it's at the very least "unidiomatic", and should definitely be avoided.

Personally, I think the word ***kind*** in the second version is both completely unnecessary *and* somewhat [obsequious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsequious), so I wouldn't include it anyway. But if OP wants to (over-)emphasize the "kindliness" with which the attention was given, it's idiomatically valid to phrase it that way.

Comment: It still shouldn't be "you kind attention".

Comment: @Catija: True, but I'm sure that's just an irrelevant typo on OP's part, so I've corrected it. I further assume the non-standard capitalization is just carelessness/lack of familiarity with standard orthographic conventions, but I'm not going to bother changing that.

Comment: You're on an *English language **learners*** site... why would you ever assume those sorts of things? Capitalization is different in different languages... the OP made the "you/your" mistake twice, which argues it may *not* be a typo...

Comment: @Catija: That's as may be (I suspect it was only *twice* because OP used cut&paste), but whether OP actually knew about "correct" usage in that respect, it's not directly relevant to the usage being queried.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the word "kindly" as an adjective has gone out of use; it's old- fashioned and not easy on the ear now.

Almost all the dictionaries say that it's both an adverb and adjective.  A kindly person or act is a kind one.

I quote a few phrases from a few dictionaries:

kindly old lady, kindly act- Cambridge. Kindly concern -Webster. Kindly criticism, kindly interest - The Free Dictionary.

So the sentence "Thank you for your kindly attention" is not incorrect grammatically.  However, as it's unusual to use it as an adjective, we should use "kind" which is more usual and common adjective in modern English as follows

I thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: Why do you have (your) in parenthesis?

Comment: Catija, I think it's optional   as we already have you after thank. However, I have omitted the parenthesis as I value your comments. Thanks.

Comment: Snailboat,  Cambridge and The Free Dictionary say that kindly can describe  people and acts.

Comment: Brought homemade chicken soup out of kindly concern for my health - Merriam Webster.

Comment: Catija/Snailboat, I would appreciate your comments in reply to my comments.